# How to stripe only file name from while using find command

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'm Using find command in shell script to search a file from a directory.

```
FileList=`find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz"`
```

and I'm getting result as

```
echo $FileList
/users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/filename.gz
```

I want result as "`FileList=filetname.gz`". I Would like to know how can we get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, you can use ## with parameter expansion and so:

```
FileList=$(while read fil;do echo ${fil##*/};done <<< $(find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz")"
```

ALternatively, if you have "basename" available, you could use it as follows:

```
FileList=$(while read fil;do echo "$(basename $fil)";done <<< $(find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz")"
```

Comment: i don't have basename  so,  i 'm using this  FileList=`find find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz" -type f -name "file*.gz" |  cut -d "/" -f  7`

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities (apart from the solutions already shown in Raman Sailopal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66545046/10622916))

If you use GNU find as it should be the case on Linux, you can use `find`'s `-printf` action.

```
FileList=$(find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz" -printf "%f")
```

If you only have a POSIX compatible `find`, you can filter the output.

```
FileList=$(find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz" | sed 's#.*/##')
```

The `sed` command will remove the longest part that ends with a `/`. (I use `#` instead of the ususal `/` to avoid quoting the `/` in the search pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

FileList=`find /users/tst/CS/FSP/data/out/ -name "file*.gz" -type f -name "file*.gz" |  cut -d "/" -f  8`